# Want to assign employee through dropdown button in loan table using laravel. its showing the list but not selected the employee. and assign it

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatable, using

This is my code in index.blade,php

```
<select name="assign_to" id="assign_to" data-id="{{ $application->id }}"
                                    class="form-control assignAppemp">
                                    <option value='0'>-- Select employee --</option>
                                    @foreach ($employees as $employee)

                                       <option value="{{$employee->id}}"{{($application->assign_to==$employee->id) ? 'selected':''}}>{{$employee->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

$('.assignAppemp').change(function(){
              var id = $(this).val();
              var emp_id = $(this).data('emp_id')
          
              var r = confirm("Are you sure want to assign!");
              if (r == true) {
                  $.ajax({
                      url: '{{ route('assignAppemp') }}',
                      type: 'post',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data: {
                          _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                            id: id,
                          emp_id: emp_id,

                      },
                      success: function(result) {
                          console.log(result);
                          if (result.statusCode == 1) {
                            $('#alertresponse').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">Employee Assigned Successfully <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');
                          }
                      }
                  });
              }
          });
            });
```

and this is my code in controller

```
public function assignAppemp(Request $request){
        $rules = [
          'id' => 'required',
          'emp_id' => 'required'
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['statusCode' => 0, 'message' => $validator->errors()],200);
        }

        $employee_email = User::where('id',$request->emp_id)->first()->email;
        $details = Loan::find($request->id)->toArray();
        if(Loan::where('id',$request->id)->update(['assign_to'=>$request->emp_id])){
            Mail::to($employee_email)->send(new SendEmployeeMail($details));
            return response()->json(['statusCode' => 1],200);
            
    }
  }
```

and I get employees from:-
$employees = User::where('role',4)->get();

its show the dropdown button with employee list. but when i select it nothing happen. not even its show the confirm message Are you sure want to assign. not able to find the error.
if possible please somebody guide me.